# R using a while loop to find number of timesteps

Tags: r, while-loop

I need to find how many timesteps my equation will run to until the population becomes extinct (N=0). I am pretty sure this will not happen since I am using the equation for geometric growth.

```
lambda=0.8
TimeSteps=10

# From previous example 
t=-c(1:TimeSteps)
N=-numeric()
N0=10
N[1]=N0
for(t in 1:TimeSteps) {
   N[t+1]=(N[t]*lambda)
}
```

I am trying to state that timesteps will equal the x value in where N is less than or equal to zero.

Comment: Take a look at my edits and make sure I didn't change your intent.  What `x` value are you referring to?  Also, this might be a better candidate for stats exchange if you don't have a specific R question.

Comment: Well, yes, it is pretty easy to establish that `N[i]` is `N0 * lambda^(i-1)` so *theoretically* it will never reach zero.

Comment: This recursive series will never be exactly zero, ever. But it will also get arbitrarily close. Maybe you should think about a small epsilon that is close enough to zero? then use `while(N[t]>epsilon) {...  t=t+1 }`

Comment: Hmmm. If it's a "population" in the biological sense, then N is an integer.